# connectivity error in DERBY

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

i am using my following code in eclipse using derby database,but getting the error as

```
Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:322)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:273)
    at jdbc.JDBCSample.main(JDBCSample.java:19)."
```

package jdbc;

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCSample {

public static void main( String args[]) {

String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://127.0.0.1:8080/SAMPLE";
// Change the connection string according to your db, ip, username and password

try {

    // Load the Driver class.
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    // If you are using any other database then load the right driver here.

    //Create the connection using the static getConnection method
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (connectionURL);

    //Create a Statement class to execute the SQL statement
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    //Execute the SQL statement and get the results in a Resultset
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select moviename, releasedate from movies");


    // Iterate through the ResultSet, displaying two values
    // for each row using the getString method

    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println("Name= " + rs.getString("moviename") + " Date= " + rs.getString("releasedate"));
    con.close();

}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {


}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please tell us on which line the `Exception` occurs and post also the stack trace?

Comment: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:322)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:273)
 at jdbc.JDBCSample.main(JDBCSample.java:19)

Comment: m getting run time errors.....

Comment: [Reference](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/devguide/rdevcsecure26537.html)

Comment: Yes working  thanks...Really helpfull......

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be solved, if you 
call `getConnection("..", "..", "..")` method with username and password. 
Example

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "sa", "sa");
```