# Java SQL expected 6 bytes and received 0 error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I am getting this error: "Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated." When I try to connect to my data base. I can not seem to find any solution that works. Could you guys give me a hand?

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class RetrieveData 
{
    private String zone;
    private String date;
    private String userName = "User";
    private String password = "Password";
    private String serverAdress= "jdbc:derby://Server:1010/Database";
    private Connection con = null;  
    private Statement stmt = null;  
    private ResultSet rs = null; 
    RetrieveData(String zoneToPull, String dayToPull)
    {
        zone = zoneToPull;
        date = dayToPull;
    }

    public int HistoryActual()
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(serverAdress, userName, password);
            String sql = "SELECT TOP 10 " +
                                "*" +
                            "FROM" +
                                "walks" +
                            "WHERE"+
                                "company_id = 'TMS3'";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) 
            {  
                System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));  
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally 
        {  
            if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
            if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
            if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}  
        } 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at RetrieveData.HistoryActual(RetrieveData.java:27)
>       at BookToGoals.(BookToGoals.java:34)
>       at Console.Console(Console.java:96)
>       at Console.access$0(Console.java:47)
>       at Console$1.run(Console.java:43)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: ERROR 08006: Insufficient data while reading from the network - expected a minimum of 6 bytes and received only 0 bytes.  The connection has been terminated.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.fill(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.ensureALayerDataInBuffer(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.readDssHeader(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.Reply.startSameIdChainParse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readExchangeServerAttributes(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readServerAttributesAndKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowServerAttributesAndKeyExchange(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowUSRIDPWDconnect(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
>       ... 22 more

Comment: can you please add stack trace as part of your question?

Comment: Also describe how your derby database is setup.  Is this the in process file based database you are using or is there really a separate process running the derby database?

Comment: The database is ran on a separate server. Its main use is with another program. I am just trying to pull data from it.

Comment: Is your database host name, username and password, all correct? Looking at your code, it seems you have copied it from some reference and forgot to replace actual username, password and hostname (in place of Server)

Comment: Yes it is correct. If i change anything I get unkownHostException. I changed it to not give out the sensitive information

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165882/connectivity-error-in-derby

Comment: Yes it seemed his problem was not putting in a user name or password. I looked thru the refrence link and couldn't find any solution in there

Comment: @Ardel, did you try adding this statement Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); before DriverManager.getConnection(.., .., ..)

Comment: Added Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); but still same error as above

Comment: I know you might have already gone through, but I recommend you to take a look at https://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/start_toc.html and check whether you missed something

Comment: Are there any server-side errors reported in the server's derby.log?

Comment: @JavaHopper I had not been there nor did I install a plug in for Derby. I was following the tutorial here http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connect_to_a_database_using_java_code.html

Comment: @BryanPendleton I could not find the logs. Do you know the default location those logs would be at? Would they be on the local machine java is installed on or to they get placed on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I found out what is going on. It is due to my own confusion. I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL database. Thus I need the sqljdbc driver not derby. This has resolve my issue. Thanks for the help guys.